# Locking Command Line Text Output While Thread Completes Without Slowing Entire Program?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have a command line tool that is running parallel threads.  These threads output to the command line.

The problem I'm having is command line prompts are getting jumbled together from multiple threads outputting text concurrently.

Logger is also jumbling text prompts.

I can imagine that all command line prompts could be outputs to a variable lock display module.  But that's a significant code refactoring.  Plus it will slow down the code.

Is there another simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the threads output data by using the `print()` function, you could interpose your own print function before starting the threads. Your print could store output in a queue, which will not slow down the code (but the queue may grow). A new single thread would read data from the queue and write it to the display.

Comment: Concurrent threads are printing to the command line.  Logger is too.  Currently I have all command line prompts running through a menu & display output module.  I could make those modules display output via a cue in blocks.  But, how do I know when the logger is going to post to the command line?  If the block display block starts to run, and a logger posts to the command line concurrently, I still have the same problem?  Or am I missing something with your suggested architecture?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what a menu & display output module is, but can't you plug the loggers to the same queue ?

Comment: I'm using pythons logging module.  I've never found any way to  define a stream output in a way that it would use the display module?  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is this *display* module ?

Comment: I have a separate module for parsing & displaying data and/or adding appropriate sound notifications.  Module receives the data to display, parses according to what is in the data, and adds sound notifications according to params passed to it.  I would love to be able to pipe the logger messages to it too.  So far, I can't seem to find a way to define the logger stream to use the module.

Comment: In the logging module, there is a QueueHandler class which supports sending logging messages to a  queue.